# Member variables in a class are private by deafult? Why does my code still work?

Tags: java, oop

Members of a class are private by deafult. The following code doesn't work.

```
#include<iostream.h>
class Test
{

int x;
};
void main()
{       Test test = new Test();
        test.x=10;

}
```

However the same code works in Java?

```
class Test { 
        int x=5;
}


public class MyClass{
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test test = new Test();
        System.out.println(test.x);
  }
}
```

According to me it should not work.. since int x is private by deafult, it should not be available to MyClass.

Comment: Java doesn't have `struct`.

Comment: variable can not be `private` until you use `private` modifier for that variable.(_In Java_)

Comment: If only Java had a freely available tutorial... Wait: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

No visibility modifier does *not* indicate that the member is `private`. If members were `private` by default, why would the `private` keyword be allowed on members? That'd be rather redundant.

Instead, no visibility modifier on a member means that the field is *package-private* -- that is, only visible to other classes in the same package as the member.

Also, `struct` doesn't exist in Java. You might be getting confused with another language... The only place where members are public by default are interfaces (and maybe enums?), provided the containing interface/enum is also public.

Answer (score 0):

I think the default modifier is package private. Thus you can use test.x in a class which is in the same package as class Test.